# How to Call and Compare Previous Guesses to One Another in a Guessing Game

Tags: python

I apologize if there is a answer to this question on a previous post. I seen a few posts about guessing games but couldn't seem to find how to recall a guess and see if it was closer then the previous one. I'm a complete beginner in python, I want the game to indicate if the first guess is within 10 or not, then say warmer or colder base on the next guesses. Thank you in advance.

```
from random import randint

win = randint(1,101)

count = 0 

while True:
    try:
        result = int(input('Guess a number between 1 and 100 \n'))
        if result > 100 or result < 1:
            print('oops, pick between 1 and 100!')
            continue
    except:
        print("oops, that's not a number!")
        continue

    if result == win:
        print(f"YOU WON, it took you {count} guesses")
        count += 1
        break

    else:
        if abs(result - win) <= 10:
                print("HOT WITHIN 10")
                count += 1
                continue
        elif abs(result - win) > 10:
            print("COLD ")
            count += 1
            continue

                # call previous guess
                # if abs(win - new_guess) < (previous_guess - win)
                # print warmer
                # else print colder
```

Comment: You can retain past guesses with a list.  Initialize it with `past_guesses = []`, add to it with `past_guesses.append(some_guess)`, know the size of your list with `len(past_guesses)`, and access each guess with `past_guesses[n]`.  As to how to compare the previous guesses, that's what programming all about...figuring out what your code needs to do to reach your goal.  For someone to answer that, they'd be doing your work for you.  That's not what this site is generally about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some modification on your code to print warmer or colder based on previous guess:

```
from random import randint

win = randint(1,101)
count = 1
prev_guess = guess = None

while True:
    try:
        prev_guess = guess
        guess = int(input('Guess a number between 1 and 100 \n'))
        if guess > 100 or guess < 1:
            print('oops, pick between 1 and 100!')
            continue
    except:
        print("oops, that's not a number!")
        continue

    if guess == win:
        print(f"YOU WON, it took you {count} guesses")
        count += 1
        break

    else:
        guess_dist = abs(guess - win)  # _dist for distance to the win number
        print(guess, prev_guess)

        if guess_dist <= 10:
            if not prev_guess or abs(prev_guess - win) > 10:
                print("HOT WITHIN 10")
            elif guess_dist < abs(prev_guess - win):
                print('warmer')
            else:
                print('colder')

        elif guess_dist > 10:
            print("COLD ")

        count += 1
        continue
```